# Como listar valores de várias consultas em uma única tabela?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela com as colunas atendente, total/dia e total/mês.

Listei na tr/td os nomes das pessoas através da primeira consulta MYSQL. Preciso através da segunda consulta somar os registros dessas pessoas e imprimir na próxima td. O problema é que as consultas são de tabelas diferentes e não sei como posso fazer para imprimir dentro de um tr através do While valores de consultas de tabelas MYSQL diferentes.

```
$nome = $_SESSION['usuarioNome'];
$nomes = mysql_query("SELECT nome FROM usuarios"); //primeira consulta
$consulta = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM atendimento WHERE nome = '$nome' AND DAY(data)=DAY(NOW())"); // segunda consulta
```

Segue HTML:

```
            <table style="text-align: center;width: 100%;" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="table_id">
            <thead>
                <tr style="background-color: #007bff;">

                  <td style="width: 5%;color: white;font-size: 16px;">Atendente:</td>
                  <td style="width: 4%;color: white;font-size: 16px;">Total/Dia:</td>
                  <td style="width: 4%;color: white;font-size: 16px;">Total/Mês:</td>

                </tr>
            </thead>
              <tbody>

                <?php  while($prod = mysql_fetch_array($nomes)) { ?>

                  <tr data-id="<?php echo $prod['id'] ?>">
                    <td style="width: 5%;color: black;font-size: 16px;"><?php echo $prod['nome'] ?></td>
                    <td style="width: 5%;color: black;font-size: 16px;"><?php  ?></td>
                    <td style="width: 5%;color: black;font-size: 16px;"><?php  ?></td>
                  </tr>

                <?php } ?>

              </tbody>
        </table>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E se unirmos as querys não ficaria melhor ?

Ficaria algo assim:

```
SELECT 
    nome,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ATENDIMENTO WHERE NOME = '$nome' AND DAY(data)=DAY(NOW())) AS TOTAL_DIA
FROM USUARIOS
```

Desta forma você consegue iterar normalmente:

```
<?php  while($prod = mysql_fetch_array($nomes)) { ?>
  <tr data-id="<?php echo $prod['id'] ?>">
    <td style="width: 5%;color: black;font-size: 16px;"><?php echo $prod['nome'] ?></td>
    <td style="width: 5%;color: black;font-size: 16px;"><?php echo $prod['TOTAL_DIA'] ?></td>
    <td style="width: 5%;color: black;font-size: 16px;"><?php  ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Deu certo!
Muito obrigado

Comment: @Well que bom que funcionou. A melhor forma de agradecer é colocar a resposta como correta. Fico grato em ajudar!